# How to interchange x, y coordinate of Geopandas Polygon?

Tags: geopandas, shapefile

my geopandas shapefile has Polygon geometry. I need to translate (x, y) coordinates of that polygon. I tried TRANSLATE property of GeoSeries, but no luck.

**Current**   POLYGON ((-78.55 74.89, -79.48 74.94))

**Expected output:**

```
POLYGON ((74.89 -78.55, 74.94 -79.48))
```

[image]

Comment: I also tried TRANSFORM from shapely.


sensitivity_data.geometry.map(lambda polygon: shapely.ops.transform(lambda x, y: (y, x), polygon))

Answer (score 1):

For non-point geometries (where you can't use `.x` and `.y` and recreate points easily), there are some other options.

The first is to the use the `transform` function, as you mentioned in the comment:

```py
import shapely.ops
import geopandas

# create GeoSeries with polygons
s = geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt(["POLYGON ((1 11, 2 12, 3 13, 3 11, 1 11))"])

>>> s
0    POLYGON ((1.00000 11.00000, 2.00000 12.00000, ...
dtype: geometry

>>> s.apply(lambda geom: shapely.ops.transform(lambda x, y: (y, x), geom))
0    POLYGON ((11.00000 1.00000, 12.00000 2.00000, ...
dtype: geometry
```

Alternatively, you could also use an "affine transform". `translate` is actually one of the predefined affine transforms, but doesn't allow to swap x and y. For that we need a custom transform matrix, using [`shapely.affinity.affine_transform`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.affinity.affine_transform):

```py
import shapely.affinity

>>> s.apply(lambda geom: shapely.affinity.affine_transform(geom, [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]))
0    POLYGON ((11.00000 1.00000, 12.00000 2.00000, ...
dtype: geometry
```

The matrix specified above basically means that the transformed coordinates become `x' = 0 * x + 1 * y` and `y' = 1 * x + 0 * y`, effectively swapping x and y.